# Sprites VS Larger Images

Tags: html, css, image, css-sprites

While doing some performance testing on my website, I noticed that the 3 images on the home page were taking 1 second per image to load.

These images are 3 1000 x 1000 high def images that only load on the homepage.

I was thinking about turning those 3 into a sprite sheet to reduce the load time of the website.

Do you think this is a good idea? I know that sprites work well with small images, but I have never tried it with 3 1000px images that are high def.

Would if be better to use the sprite or just keep them loaded individually?

I found a few similar questions online but was not able to come to a conclusion.

Comment: I feel like I will end up compressing the images down to decrease the size. Right now there is almost no compression on the images.

Comment: If you can wait for one long request (e.g. use spinner), you can use your "big sprite".

Comment: @Learn12 that's probably the first thing you should try. It depends on the content, but JPG photos can usually be compressed to 70% without visible artifacts, sometimes even more... again, depends on the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, the problem that sprites solves is meant mostly when there are many and small images. So instead of making 100 requests to a server you make a single one.

When using large images you won't get much benefit from this concept. Also with larger images, it's better if the first image get's loaded and you could render it to a user and meanwhile load other images.

Third option would be to render some small thumbnails 20x20 pixels JPG files(usually <~10KB size), and then stretch these to the same size as the larger ones. This causes some blurry image but it's understandable what's on the image. Now when the larger images gets loaded you replace the small ones. This requires additional JavaScript execution.

Comment: +1 Also, another possible downside is the file size which is possibly larger than the sum of 3 individual files because of how compression works.

Comment: True, also before uploading make sure you optimize your images, use compression, correct cache headers and CDN.

Comment: Yes thank you. I have realized that now that even if I add the 3 images in a sprite sheet, I will have only 1 call to the server but the file size will still be large. I have decided to add some compression to the images, looks like 80 is the default usually. I will also look into making a media CDN.